# Are these the same "check this one off your list" & "check this one off on your list"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

According to [oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/check-off)

> **check somebody/something off** (North American English) (British English tick somebody/something off)
>
> to put a mark (✓) beside a name or an item on a list to show that
>   something has been dealt with
>
> *Check the names off as the guests arrive.*
>
> *As I packed my case I checked everything off on my list.*

But a lot of natives say "**check this one off your list**".

This could be very confused because it may mean "**remove / cross out / uncheck this item out of your list**"

But I guess "**check this one off your list**" & "**check this one off *on* your list**" are the same.

So, Are these the same "**check this one off your list**" & "**check this one off *on* your list**"?

**Note**: 
"**check this one off your list**" was said by an American & American often omits preposition "**on**". Eg. American says "*I'll see you Monday*"="*I'll see you on Monday*". I am not sure if that is the main reason

Comment: If a preposition is inserted between "off" and "your list", I think it's usually "of", not "on": _check this one off **of** your list_. If you hear "on", though,  I think the two expressions are probably intended to mean the same thing, and the added preposition is largely extraneous.

Comment: @J.R., I think that is how American says as they often leave out the preposition "**on**". Eg, American says "*I'll see you Monday*"="*I'll see you on Monday*"

Comment: I agree with @J.R., "off of" is more commonly used than "off on", but yes they mean the same. The dictionary example could be expanded to "As I packed my case I checked everything off [that was] on my list."

Comment: Interesting. I would "tick something off a list". I could conceivably "tick someone off" – meaning that I had rebuked them.  Perhaps that's only Australian English usage. I would not use "check off" naturally; neither would I use "off of".  It seems incorrect to me, but obviously, usage differs around the English-speaking world.  See: off | Definition of off in English by Oxford Dictionaries